# Erroring out for passed argument less than 1, what am I doing?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to get a script to echo a message when a number like -9 is entered.

The arguments have to be passed from the command line

This is what I have now.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Assign1part1

if (( $# != 1 )); then
    echo "Error: Must only enter one argument" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if (( $1 -lt 1 )); then
    echo "Error: Argument must be a positive integer" >&2
    exit 1
fi

seq -s, $1 -1 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[[` and `]]`, not `((` and `))`. The former is testing, the latter is expression evaluation which allows for `!=` but not `-lt`.

On top of that, your first error message is slightly off, making it sound like you've entered more arguments than you should have, even in the case where you enter none. It would be better phrased as something like `"Must enter exactly one argument"`.

And, since `$#` is numeric, I prefer using the numeric comparisons, `-ne` rather than `!=` in this particular case.

In other words:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Assign1part1

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Error: Must enter exactly one argument" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $1 -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Error: Argument must be a positive integer" >&2
    exit 1
fi

seq -s, $1 -1 1
```

Running that with certain test data gives:

```
pax> testprog 5
5,4,3,2,1

pax> testprog 9
9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

pax> testprog
Error: Must enter exactly one argument

pax> testprog 1 2
Error: Must enter exactly one argument

pax> testprog -7
Error: Argument must be a positive integer
```

Comment: bash likes `((` and `))`. But `((` does not like `-lt`.

Comment: hmm.. do you mean the {{ or the [[ because the [[ does nothing for me it seems.

Comment: And, I tip my hat to you good sir.  Is there a method to chat with people or tip people financially on this site?  You guys deserve some of mah cash for your sweet skills

Comment: @Looking2learned: no, just vote up useful and accept best answers. That's the currency in use here.

Answer (score 2):

`(( ... ))` is not `test`.

```
$ (( -1 < 1 )) ; echo $?
0
$ (( -1 > 1 )) ; echo $?
1
```